# why angular not bind Image value into serverside

Tags: angularjs

Here i'm using anguar with bootstrap i'm able to binding textvales not why my image not binding

**Html**

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Emil" ng-model="Email" />
   <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" ng-model="Image"  ngf-select>
            <img ngf-thumbnail="Image" />
             <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Login" ng-click="Uplode(Image)" />
        </div>
```

**Angular.Js**

```
$scope.Uplode = function (file) {
        if ($scope.Image != null) {
            //   if ((Image.type == 'image/png' || Image.type == 'image/jpeg' || Image.type == 'image/gif') && Image.size <= (512 * 1024)) {

            if (file.type == 'image/png' || file.type == 'image/jpg' || file.type == 'image/gif' || file.type == "image/jpeg")
                {
                if (file.size <= (512 * 1024))
                {
                    if (file == file)
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
                            dataAsFormData.append(file[i].name, file[i]);
                        }
                    } 
                    var xx = {
                        Image: $scope.file,
                        Email: $scope.Email,
                        password: $scope.password,}
                    var service = MyserviceContect.DataSave(xx);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var i=file.name;
var x={
Image:i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in your `$scope.Upload()` function you are passing `file` and at `var xx = {...}` you are accessing it with `$scope.file` which would be undefined.
Do:

```
var xx = {
    Image: file,
    Email: $scope.Email,
    password: $scope.password
}
```

Comment: no error but value not binding have u any alternate solution

Comment: could you log the variable xx and tell me its output?

Comment: xx = Object {Image: File, Email: undefined, password: undefined}
18
                        Image: file,
file = File {name: "1.jpg", lastModified: 1479029060761, lastModifiedDate: Sun Nov 13 2016 14:54:20 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webki

Comment: What are you expecting to have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128838/discussion-between-evans-murithi-and-waheed-mohammad).